# Why every small set is a moderate set, but not conversely (as universe itself)?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I read [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+set)

> a subset of the universe, which may be small or large. (every small set is moderate, but not conversely; again, the universe itself is the standard counterexample.)

But I don't understand well because the universe itself is the standard counterexample, i.e why every small set is moderate, but not conversely ?

This because universe is a [pure set](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set) ?
This situation is for me cryptic.

**Why can't the universe belong to itself ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you link is about foundations in general. In each foundation the precise reason that a universe cannot contain itself may be different.

For example, in ZFC, the axiom of regularity forbids that any set contains itself. So in that system, if we have a set that functions as a universe, it cannot contain itself.

The more general answer is that having a universe contain itself would give us [Russell's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox):

Most foundations will have some form of separation. That is, given a set $X$ in our universe, and some first-order formula $\varphi$, we can form a set
$$
Y = \{x \in X : \varphi(x)\},
$$
such that $Y$ is again in our universe. If our universe $U$ contains itself,  we could build the set
$$
R = \{ x \in U : x \not \in x\},
$$
which would be in $U$. But now we have that $R \in R$ if and only if $R \not \in R$, which is problematic.

Comment: In your conclusion *we have that* $R \in R$ *if and only if* $R \not \in R$* we can separate in 2 different contexts the 1st $R \in R$ *when* it is related to that 2nd $R \not \in R$. In your conclusion I note a kind of semantic modulation when you had typed your condition **if and only if** because is like you placed on the same plane $R \not \in R$ and $R \not \in R$ but error is that you treated as linear independence relation when, for me, that relation or condition **if and only if** puts $R \in R$ and $R \not \in R$ in a position of a Linear independence. This for me is problematic